# React.JS run script inner IFrame

Tags: reactjs, typescript, iframe, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I'm integrating a payment system. When i call payment system API it give me a htmlContent. So i want to run this htmlString inner a iframe. When i run the htmlContent inner iframe the scripts doesn't work.

It's a example about run script inner iframe.

```js
const IFrame = ({ children, ...props }: any) => {
  const [contentRef, setContentRef] = useState<any>(null);
  const mountNode = contentRef?.contentWindow?.document?.body;

  return (
    // eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/iframe-has-title
    <iframe
      {...props}
      ref={setContentRef}
      style={{ border: 0 }}
      onLoad={(e: any) => {
        console.log('page loaded', e.target);
      }}
    >
      {mountNode && createPortal(children, mountNode)}
    </iframe>
  );
};
```

My render code block

```js
  const html = "<html>Hello</html><script>alert('world');</script>";
  return (
          <IFrame>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
          </IFrame>
         );
```

When i run this code i didn't get any alert inner iframe. My main issue is;
For example when i run this htmlContent it redirecting a url with post some forms. I want to listen the url also for catch success url callback.
How can i do it? When i code React-Native i solve this problem with WebView i can run htmlContent on WebView but i cannot find any way to do it in React.JS